# Duplicate Marker Error in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html

How do you deal with the markers in Leaflet Map? My question here is that when i place a marker on the map and place another different marker in the map the first marker always come or combined with the other image.

Here is my Code

```
var note = document.getElementById('note');
var datepick = document.getElementById('demo1');
var timepick = document.getElementById('timepick');
        layerpoly.on('click', function(e){
        var markerB = new L.Marker(e.latlng,{icon: Icon3});
        markerB.bindPopup("HOMICIDE</br>Date:"+datepick.value+"</br>Time:"+timepick.value+"</br>Address:"+note.value+"").addTo(map);
    map.addlayer(markerB);
closure2 (markerB)
```

is there something wrong in click event i just want that no other markers will come together with the marker i selected? any help is appreciated TYIA!

Comment: The output of this code is im always placing two markers at the click event (the last marker that i selected and put on map and the marker i currently selected) which is wrong because i only select fire "Marker" but when i place it on the map the Water "Marker" always comes with the Fire "Marker" you know? double marker shows in one click

Comment: Would it be possible for you to set up a jsfiddle to illustrate the issue better?

Comment: Ahmm Sir, I cant promise but while you waiting you can see this post because it contains the whole code of my problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277429/image-improper-layer-on-leaflet-mapmarker

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/aeqohj.jpg

Sir Im sorry its too hard to create a jsfiddle of this because of many codes,by the way sir the link above shows to you what i mean. the image on the upper left side of the map is the first image i selected and on the right down side is the second image or marker with the first image combined. :(

Comment: Ok. No probs. If you can get the markers to work in isolation, you will have a much better chance of understanding what's going on in your original problem. Maybe you will need to change some of the instantiation logic or something.

Comment: what do you mean sir? because i try everything and yet same output always show, i tried if/else but nothing happens. this is my problem since last week

Comment: Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/fJFWN/17/ . I mean you could try to play around with the markers there. Maybe that would show what's wrong with the original approach.

Comment: Whoo, too hard anyway thank you for the help i will figure this out by myself and i you will help me about this again